# app icon is occasionally missing at ios13/14/15

Tags: ios, iphone

After our app was launched, there were singles user feedback that the app icon was missing and the screenshot was attached:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm9GV.png)

Feedback models are：

- iPhone 8（iOS13.3）
- iPhone 13（iOS 15.4.1）
- iPhoneX（iOS14.4.2）

We use the same device as the user and this problem does not occur；

At present, we suspect that we used the single size app icon to set the app icon in the early version, which may be a system compatibility problem, but it cannot be verified；

Ask for help, have you encountered the same situation again, how to solve, thank you

The app icon is displayed normally